# Partly out vs Partly

Tags: grammar, context

"In August of 1930, a Norwegian sloop, the Bratvaag, sailing in the
Arctic Ocean, stopped at a remote island called White Island.The Bratvaag was **partly** on a scientiɹc mission, led by a geologist named Dr. Gunnar Horn, and **partly out** sealing", The Ice Balloon, Alec Wilkinson.

What is the difference between blond type expressions?

Are they replaceable in general?

Comment: **Out** is linked to **sealing**, not to **partly**.

Comment: @KateBunting Yes, If you were talking about two separate trips you would say "In July the Bratvaag was on a scientific meission and In August the Bratvaag was out sealing".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We go "on" a mission.

**Example**

*Where is agent 007?*

*He has gone on a mission.*

---

A ship can go "out" into the ocean doing some action such as fishing or sealing.

**Example**

*The lifeboat has gone out looking for survivors.*

---

The sentence is badly written. If we assume the Bratvaag to be a ship, it makes no sense for part of the ship to be doing one thing and another part to be somewhere else, doing something different.

Comment: I've just added more information. What do you think?

Comment: Yes, it is badly written. It would have been better to say _The purpose of the voyage was partly a scientific mission... and partly sealing._